# In Python how to use variables in call function?

Tags: python, call, mousemove, xdotool

I am using Python on Ubuntu.
`call(["xdotool", "mousemove", "500","600"])`works fine.

But if `x=500`, `y=600`,

`call(["xdotool", "mousemove", "x","y"])`
does not work.

What should be the syntax of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Remove the quotes.  `"x"` is a string (containing the single letter x).

Comment: I also tried that but it was not working.

Comment: @Sam How so? Please provide the code you tried and the traceback (the error) :)

Comment: "not working" isn't helpful, alas.  Say *exactly* what happened, including the full text of any error message and traceback.  And show the exact code you used.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./checkstate.py", line 53, in <module>
    call(["xdotool", "mousemove",x,y])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Comment: Use `str(x)` and `str(y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it like this

```
call(["xdotool", "mousemove", str(x), str(y)])
```

`x` and `y` are variables which are pointing to data. But when you say, `"x"` and `"y"`, you are passing the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes. If you keep quotes, it will treat as a string.

`call(["xdotool", "mousemove", "500","600"])`